# Why is Heroku ejs file name case sensitive?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I deployed my nodejs app to heroku. I kept on getting

> Error: Failed to lookup view "Details" in views directory "/app/views"
>   Heroku

The app was working fine in my local computer. I then realized that the view name was saved as lower case **details** rather than **Details**.

Why does doing

```
res.render("Details")
```

work on my local computer but does not work on Heroku?

Comment: Because your local computer is case insensitive (Windows?) but Heroku's isn't?